# Rename a file that begins with "-"

Tags: mv

Well it looks like I got myself stuck.  There's no GUI on this system as I have to PUTTY in.  File begins with the "-" sign and I can't seem to escape out of it with \, " or '.

```
mv -output.txt output.txt
mv: invalid option -- 'o'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Same issue with cat, less, vim, etc...

I

Answer (score 0):

`mv -- -output.txt output.txt`

`--` signifies the end of command options, which allows all text after that to be treated as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Another idea besides `--` is

```
mv ./-output.txt output.txt
```

(You need to be in the current directory of course)